# PHP replacing $_SESSION with $_COOKIE syntax differences

Tags: php, cookies

New to PHP Sessions and Cookies.

I have an old login script that I'm trying to upgrade to work with a new cross sub-domain feature.  It was all written with `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE`. (From what I've ready, anything set to a SESSION var doesn't carry over cross domain, even after I've set the cookie params for the entire domain and root directory).

If I do a Search and Replace for `$_SESSION` and change it to `$_COOKIE`, am I going to have to make a lot of syntax changes, or do mostly operate the same way?

Comment: Replacing `$_SESSION` with `$_COOKIE` on a login script will probably introduce an authentication bypass vulnerability. Are you aware session data is stored server side and cookie data is all client side (and so can be tampered with)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is in general a very bad idea. Using cookies for all session related data means that you maybe publish internal data. So you would make it for an attacker quiet easy to get admin rights if you would habe a cookie isAdmin=false. Also all Cookies are transmitted on every request, which also causes more traffic.

Please note also that cookies are set with the function setcookie(). $_COOKIE is normally read only.

Comment: So, for non security vulnerable things like layout data and simple non-descript user ID's, cookies would be ok?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't put user IDs in cookies either. Simply store a session key (e.g., random string) in the cookie and keep all of the other information on the server (e.g., in a database). That way, even if an attacker got the information, it would be meaningless as soon as the session expired (and, if you're doing extra checks such as IP, browser, etc, you can make it meaningless to others immediately).

Comment: So a session key is generated, saved to a temp table on a DB with all the user info and then, if/when that session expires, drop the temp table?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` can be used to read and write session data. `$_COOKIE` is used to read.

A potential problem with setting cookies is that they must be set using `setcookie` before any browser output... this may break your code if `$_SESSION` is being used to write session data during or after page rendering (because session data can be set at any time).

Cross domain sessions would be a security vulnerability, and from the sounds of it, crossdomain cookies when dealing with user credentials.

Comment: I follow what you're saying.  I'm not really storing any data that poses a security threat, as far as pass words and private info but more like user id#s and layout info.  Nothing that is personal or sensitive